# Loss not decreasing past certain threshold

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

recently I've been experimenting with convolutional neural networks and have set about a simple task. The task is just to draw bounding boxes around a triangle and rectangle that exist in an image.

My model setup:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100, 100, 1));

conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(5, 5, 1), padding="same")(inputs)
maxpool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv1);

conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(maxpool1);
maxpool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv2);

flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(maxpool2)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(70, activation="relu")(flatten);

bounding_box_rect = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="bounding_box_rect")(dense);
bounding_box_triangle = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="bounding_box_triangle")(dense);

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[bounding_box_rect, bounding_box_triangle], name="CNN");
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss={"bounding_box_rect" : "mean_squared_error", "bounding_box_triangle" : "mean_squared_error"}, metrics=["accuracy"], run_eagerly=True);
```

The network has 8 outputs; the first 2 denote the middle coordinates of the rectangle, and the next 2 denote the length and width of the rectangle. The next 2 denote the middle coordinates of the triangle, and the last 2 denote the base and height of the triangle.

Example of [training sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmKC3.png)
(I have confirmed that each training sample has different inputs and different and correct bounding boxes for each shape)

When training, the loss does decrease. Once it reaches a certain threshold, however, it just lingers there. As well, the network ends up predicting basically the same values no matter the input. (Very near to being the exact same) I have also confirmed that the network predicts random values prior to training.

After I compiled my training data, I plotted the image and bounding boxes and they seemed to match up. However, when fed to the network, it does not learn properly.

**Example**

```
[array([[54.84601 , 55.95058 , 26.242231,  0.      ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.      ,  0.      , 24.61768 , 19.852955]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[55.77181 , 56.42903 , 25.295406,  0.      ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.      ,  0.      , 23.485985, 19.273085]], dtype=float32)]
```

Which gives: (Blue box is triangle, Red box is rectangle)

[1st prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2DE7.png)

[2nd Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmBc4.png)

It seems the network is choosing a bounding box for each shape that gives the least average loss between all of the training samples (or something similar). Why could this be happening?

Comment: Hello there! More often than not this occurs due to applying a preprocessing A in images during training (say minmax scaling) and a preprocessing B (or nothing) before predicting the bounding boxes for your examples. Make sure this is not the case, you need to apply the exact same  preprocessing. Also, accuracy as a metric shouldn't do it in this case but this is not relevant to your issue, just an observation.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; if I did add some sort of preprocessing during training and none during testing, I still don't understand why the loss during training does not go below some value. As well I use the same functions to gather training and testing data.(100x100 matrix, 0 is empty, 2 denotes a pixel that belongs to a triangle, and 3 is a pixel that belongs to a rectangle) Should I be normalizing this data maybe?

Comment: NNs love inputs in ranges say 0 to 1. If the input goes from 0 to 1million then the weights will be far more difficult to tune. The reason I asked for a confirmation on the identical preprocessing thing is because if you train a network to predict bounding boxes for inputs in [0,1] and then test it using images with values in [0,255] then chances are you'll be getting the exact same output for each image. About the loss, this doesn't imply that there's anything wrong by itself, I mean it's supposed to decrease up to a point either way. In general yeah u normalize but this may not be the issue.

Comment: Yeah; I've normalized the inputs within 0 and 1 and the issue still seems to arise.

Comment: What's weird is when I remove either the triangle or the rectangle from the training/testing data, it works completely fine. It's only when they're combined together that this issue arises

Comment: @avidprogrammer I could be wrong but the model might be too "simple". Also, are you feeding your in your training data as mini-batches?

Comment: It ended up being some weird formatting error I did with creating my training labels; (doing [[1, 2, 3, 4]] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4]). Not sure how that caused any of this but it seems to be fixed now.